# minimum number of points a convex hull must have

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Quick question:

Say for example there are 10 colinear points. my question is does a convex hull *have* to be a convex polygon? or can it be a line as well according to the formal definition of the convex hull?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convex hull of 10 collinear points is the line segment between the two extreme points.

No, a convex hull does not have to be convex polygon. A convex hull can be a point, a line segment, a ray, a line, a convex polygon, a circular sector, a half plane, a cubic, etc. .

A definition in math, such as [the definition of convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Definitions), is the strictest kind of definition. It means exactly what it says. No more, no less.